# React hooks updating parent state through child and rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have components that are dependent on the parent state. When I pass in the parent useState hook to the child, the component does not seem to render.

on my `ChildA` component, I call a function to perform props.updateFiles(). `ChildB` has nothing rendered even after the prop has changed.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

    return (
      <div>
        <ChildA files={files} updateFiles={setFiles} />
        <ChildB files={files} updateFiles={setFiles} />
      </div>
    );
  };
export default Parent;
```

```
const ChildA = (props) => {
  const appendFile = () => {
    let old = props.files;
    old.push({ name: "asdf" });
    props.updateFiles(old);
  };

  return (
    <div >
        <button onClick={appendFile}>append file</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ChildA;
```

```
const ChildB = (props) => {

  const renderProps = (items) => {
    let out = items.map(({ name }, index) => <div>{name}</div>);
    return out;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {renderProps(props.files)}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ChildB;
```

Comment: You'll need to show ChildA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not utilizing the `useState` hook correctly when it comes to adding an item to an array. You'll need to utilize the `...` spread operator. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
const appendFile = () => {
   let old = props.files;
   props.updateFiles([...old, "asdf"]);
};
```

Also, when utilizing some events such as mousemove, you'll need to use the callback version:

```
const appendFile = () => {
   props.updateFiles(oldArray => [...oldArray, "asdf"]);
};
```